# How to import the googleapis npm package into meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, google-api, google-api-client

I'm using the meteor framework, and trying to use google sheets to visualize some of my app's data. But for whatever reason, I can't seem to get the google api to load. I started with the command `npm i googleapis` and adding `const {google} = require('googleapis')` Which is to my knowledge correct. However, when I `console.log(google)` it spits out `undefined`.

I'm running Meteor 1.8.1, Node 6.12.0, and googleapi ^39.2.0

I would love to know what I'm doing wrong, most other people with this issue needed to update various other packages, so I've already run `npm update` To no avail, I've tried using `import { google } from 'googleapis'` Also to no avail, I saw somewhere that that would require transformations or something, but it still spits out `undefined`

I noticed that if I run `require('googleapis')` from my meteor shell, then it returns all the methods and whatnot that it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing my node_modules and running `npm i` did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Ok, how I do it, to prevent adding another NPM to my Meteor projects ...

In my main.html I have this line:
`<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//maps.googleapis.com">`

The next example shows adding google maps. I first make sure that, in a session, I load this library maximum once.

I call this code in multiple pages as I need the API. Since I use react, I do i in 'componentDidMount'.

```
if (!(window.google && window.google.maps)) {
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxx&libraries=places'
      script.defer = true
      document.head.appendChild(script)
    }
```